# Keep all line breaks except the last one using awk

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, command-line, newlines

How do I modify this line below to capture the content between two lines without the trailing line break?

```
interesting="$(awk "NR >= $first_line && NR <= $second_line" $file_path | base64 -w 0)"
```

I'm not sure if I should be looking to do this with awk, bash, or some other unix tool?

Comment: Can you give example to understand well?

Comment: Example input, example of desired output, please.

Comment: Kindly provide.input Data

Comment: Expected output

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like:

```
< "$file_path" awk -v x="$first_line" -v y="$second_line" '
  NR == x {printf "%s", $0; next}
  NR > x && NR <= y {printf "%s", ORS $0}' |
  base64 -w0
```

Comment: where do I put the $file_path ?

Comment: @AndrewWei, as input to the pipeline (see edit). The can be done by passing the file path to `awk` so `awk` opens it instead of the shell, but that wouldn't work for some values of `$file_path` (that contain `=` for instance). You also forgot the quotes around the variable.